# Ansible playbook hangs on a single host

Tags: ansible

Playbook has been simplified for quick understanding.

```
---
- hosts: web_host
  remote_user: someuser
  connection: ssh
  ignore_errors: yes

  vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d) }}"

  gather_facts: no
#  gather_subset: "!all,!min"

  tasks:

   - name: 1 | Collect all remote servers statistics

     script: /home/raman/ansible/playbooks/monitoring/mon_sys.bash
     register: CPU_Mem_Service
     tags:
       - CPU_Mem_Service_TAG
     args:
       executable: /bin/bash
     ignore_errors: yes
```

All remote hosts are on RHEL6.10
The script used in playbook has `df -h` command.

This playbook runs fine until it doesn't.

Sometimes this playbook hangs on one remote host. This "one" remote host is random.  Upon checking, by personally logging into hung remote host, I found `df` command is hanging on that host. Due to stale/dead NFS mount.

Is there a way for a ansible playbook to skip and move on and not stay stuck on the same host indefinitely?

Any suggestions?

Comment: [`async`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) and eventually [`async_status`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html) are probably your friends.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Here is the problem with async [even if I change script module with something else as it doesn't works with async].  Playbook simply hangs indefinitely.  Q: If I put, say, async: 60 on that task. Would it just go past the stuck/hung host after 60 seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

use async and poll..

The async tasks will run until they either complete, fail or timeout according to their async value.

When poll is a positive value (default 15 if unspecified), the playbook will still block on the task until it either completes, fails or times out.

When poll is 0, Ansible will start the task and immediately move on to the next one without waiting for a result.